# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: putMemberOffset

Tags: java, maven, opencv, nosuchmethoderror, fiji

I am working on windows 10 with jdk1.8 I am getting following error. I tried a lot but unable to find the reason why getting this error, error snap is as follows.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: putMemberOffset

at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:525)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:411)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:354)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:10)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:386)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:354)
at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_imgcodecs.<clinit>(opencv_imgcodecs.java:13)
at com.ob.libj.ProcessImageJavaCV.start(ProcessImageJavaCV.java:23)
at UTest.testCountThreshold(UTest.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.humble</groupId>
        <artifactId>humble-video-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I also use lastest Fiji jars.

I think it must be a compatibility problem between Opencv and Fiji because the error comes when I use both.

Have you any idea how to fix it?
thanks

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I would recommend to use dependency management tool like found in maven or gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a version compatibility problem. One of the libraries (it seems to be OpenCV) has been compiled against a version of the another (probably fiji) that contains the method in question (`putMemberOffset`) but the version that's available on the classpath when you run the application/test doesn't contain that method, hence the error.

Besides that it could be a different library that both OpenCV and fiji have been compiled against but in different versions.

To fix that use compatible versions of the libraries. To find out which ones that are you'd need to find which library is in conflict and which versions the libraries you use depend on - you should be able to see that in those libraries' documentation or pom.xml or in maven's output (you might have to enable the verbose option though).

Comment: That's work thank. Java dependencies are not easy ^^

Comment: @rtisne well, dependencies are never easy ;)